# How to empty an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im working on a game(snake) with obstacles, when the user get their score to 5 I create more blocks as obstacles:

```
wall = new Array(),
wall.push(new Rectangle(30, 50, 10, 10));
```

is there a clear/empty option in js, to delete the rectangles that i insert in the array
i try with

```
rectangle=[];
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you

Comment: _"i try with

`rectangle=[];`
but it didn't work."_ Where is `rectangle` defined ? Try `wall = []`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

1) Modify the `length` property

```
var wall = new Array(),
wall.push(new Rectangle(30, 50, 10, 10));

wall.length = 0;
```

2) Use the `splice()` method

```
wall.splice(0);
```

Check [this interesting article](http://rainsoft.io/the-magic-behind-array-length-property/) about the `length` property.